# Python telebot: как сделать, чтобы бот редактировал сообщения?

Tags: python, telegram-bot, telegram, telebot

Я не понял библиотеку PyTelegramBotAPI, как сделать, чтобы бот в ответ на сообщения не присылал новые, а редактировал старые?

Comment: При callback запросах?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вот так:

```py
bot.edit_message_text(
        chat_id=m.chat.id,
        message_id=m.message_id,
        text=f'{text}',
        parse_mode='Markdown', #не обязательно
        reply_markup=kbrd_start(), #не обязательно
)
```

А вообще, вот глянь, рабочий пример:  https://github.com/vladrunk/MagicNumberBot/blob/master/main.py